# Jamaica Blue Mountain coffee for the Emperor and his family only

Tags: story-identification, space

I'd like to find a SF novel, "space opera" type, of which I remember just one scene.

There is apparently an Emperor, either for the whole known Universe, or just some part of it. But this Emperor is probably just like the one of Japan now, he does not appear in the story except for this one reference to **respect to his person**, not to his rule.

In this Universe, Jamaica Blue Mountain coffee is extremely rare, and the entire crop is **exclusively** for the Imperial family.

There is a very rich merchant who boasts (in a very limited public, in his private spaceship, I think) that he once managed to bribe someone, at extreme risk for himself and the bribed person, and thus at an extremely high bribe, to obtain a small amount. Very good, but not worth that ridiculous high price.

There is just one single reference to the Emperor and Jamaica Blue Mountain coffee in the story but somehow I think that the merchant obsession to coffee in general plays some role, but it is very fuzzy in my mind.

This character reminds me a lot of Poul Anderson's Nicholas van Rijn, but I know that I read exactly three stories with him in a collection I have at home. I checked, it is not him.

It is also **not** one of the "Merchant Princes" in Asimov's *Foundation*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is [*The Mote in God's Eye*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mote_in_God%27s_Eye) by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle.

A wealthy merchant boasts of having drunk the Imperial-only coffee blend.

> “Have you heard of Jamaica Blue Mountain? It grows
> on Earth itself, on a large island; the island was never
> bombed, and the mutations were weeded out in the centuries following the collapse of the CoDominium. It cannot be bought. Navy ships carry it to the Imperial Palace
> on Sparta.”
> “How does it taste?”
> “As I told you, it is reserved for the Royal—” Bury
> hesitated. “Very well. You know me that well. I would
> not pay such a price again, but I do not regret it.”

Purely for the record, there are *dozens* of references to the Emperor, but you're right that he doesn't appear in person in the novel.

Comment: Most definitely it !!

Comment: Ah, the minute went by ! I remember *The Mote...*, and the Moties but not much the Emperor. Didn't the "monkey-like" Moties, the "engineers" pets, improve the coffee machine ? Now its coming back to me ...